# why can't I access Python 3.7.9 from Release Stage of Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to do some steps in the Release stage of my multi-stage Azure DevOps pipeline (written in YAML) that requires Python.  But when I do this:

```yaml
                - task: UsePythonVersion@0
                  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'
                  inputs:
                    versionSpec: '3.7.9'
```

I get this error:

Version spec 3.7.9 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.

But I'm using the windows-2019 image (for the whole pipeline), and according to this page:

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md

Python 3.7.9 is present in the image.

What could be my problem in this case?

Could it be that the Build stage is using a different agent than the Release stage? Release is attached to a Deployment Group, so perhaps the "agent" in this case is NOT windows-2019.  It's hard to know where exactly code is run in the stages because the documentation is unclear and mostly showcases simplest-possible pipelines.

If the release IS happening on the linked computer in the Deployment Group, then perhaps the content of c:\azagent is relevant here. The directory the error mentions is C:\azagent\A5_work_tool as the place where Python is supposed to be. It is indeed empty.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

How I get this issue:

```
stages:
  - stage: A
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
    jobs:
    - job: A1
      displayName: Job A1
      steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.7.9'
          addToPath: true
          architecture: 'x64'

  - stage: B
    jobs:
    - job: B1
      displayName: Job B1
      steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0 #You will get issue in this place.
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.7.9'
          addToPath: true
          architecture: 'x64'
```

How to solve this issue:

```
stages:
  - stage: A
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
    jobs:
    - job: A1
      displayName: Job A1
      steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.7.9'
          addToPath: true
          architecture: 'x64'

  - stage: B
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
    jobs:
    - job: B1
      displayName: Job B1
      steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.7.9'
          addToPath: true
          architecture: 'x64'
```